# How to decrypt this password?

Tags: database, encryption, passwords, password-encryption

A website was handed down to me and I would like to figure out what type of password encryption it uses.

Here is a password from a test account I made: $2a$08$kFdK6FeCZbFq8ZySfKlogu3lrRKnhT5yK8T3I2qXhOQSVuGtPfJhe

A way to decrypt it or the type of the encryption would be very useful.
Thanks.

Comment: read this >>> https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_encryption_hashing/

Answer (score 3):

The format is that of bcrypt. If so, you can't "decrypt" this password, because it's gone through an irreversible hashing process. But you should be able to verify that bcrypt was used by invoking bcrypt with the password for your test account, and a "cost factor" of 8. There are [online calculators](https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator) you can use for a quick test.

Answer (score 1):

You can't as it's not an encrypted password, it's a password hash (sometimes called one-way encryption). This is the right way to store passwords. As I'm guessing that you're using PHP, you can read about this on the [password_hash](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) manual page.

You really shouldn't ever have to go backwards from a hashed password to the password. When you need to verify it, call [password_verify](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). It hashes the user's clear-text password using the same hashing algorithm and compares it with the hashed password.

The other situation where you might want to reverse the password is when a user loses their password. Instead, allow the user to create a new password via an email link, text message, etc...

Storing passwords in a decryptable format leads to [embarrassing incidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_LinkedIn_hack).

Comment: I have just found the encryption key. Using this can I decrypt the password?

Comment: You can't have found the "key" as it is not an encryption. It is a hash. It is effectively impossible to reverse it. Why do you want to get the user's passwords?

Comment: I did a little more looking through the website and found it is made using codeignitor. I found this guide on password encryption and decryption. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html

Comment: I don't know what key you've found but it's not the key for that string that you posted in your question. That string is a one-way hash as documented in the [password_hash](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) PHP function. The `$2a` means that it was made using the one-way hash function bcrypt (search [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) for `2a`)

Comment: Again, why do you want to do this? You shouldn't have a need to do it.

Comment: "...would like to **figure out what type** of password encryption..."